# Alert if a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, alert

I don't know javascript, so this may be on the wrong track anyway.
I have shipping methods that can be selected via radio button. I'm trying to create an alert if a certain shipping method is selected, however the radio value changes based on the available shipping options.

```
<label id="shippingMethod"><input type="radio" name="selectedShippingMethod" id="shippingCheck" value="5"> <span class="ShipperName">Collect Shipping</span>  <em class="ShipperPrice ProductPrice">$0.00</em></label>
```

and here is the alert code I'm trying to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio[name="selectedShippingMethod"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '5'){
            alert('ALERT TEXT TO POPUP');
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a way I can make it trigger an alert based on `ShipperName` "Collect Shipping" instead of the radio value, or is there a better way to be doing this to begin with.

Comment: Does you actual code only have one radio button?

Comment: No, it has anywhere from 1 to 6. Optimally, I'd like it to call the alert strictly based on the text next to the selected radio, as I do not have control over the code behind it, and it could be changed by the shopping cart company.

Comment: So you want to `alert` the text in the span?

Comment: Assuming I understand correctly, yes. Like i said, no javascript knowledge and only basic html.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish, but taking a guess, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $radios = $('input:radio[name="selectedShippingMethod"]');

    $radios.change(function () {
        var $selected = $radios.filter(':checked');
        if ( $selected.val() == 5 ) {
            alert( $selected.parent().text() );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Silber, the only change I would suggest is setting the alert to "Collect Shipping" per the OPs original goal.

Your function helped me with a similar solution I was looking for (Thanks!)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $radios = $('input:radio[name="selectedShippingMethod"]');
  $radios.change(function () {
    var $selected = $radios.filter(':checked');
    if ( $selected.val() == 5 ) {
        alert("Collect Shipping" );
        }
    });
});
```